# Moving the camera to look at a Plane Object

Tags: html5-canvas, three.js

Hi I have been working with a map in three.js
Happens to be I have problem in facing/moving the camera to look at a Plane which happen to be like a marker in the map.

What I have here is that a line of codes derive from /threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes

Load my collada model of map and plot the google like marker in.

I turn the cube to be the marker and change to double side plane.

So when I click the marker the camera tween/move to the position of the plane but it's facing the other side of the plane or to the wrong side. Just want it to be face to face by camera.

I like it to be some kind of http://www.tweetopia.net/.

The tweetopia faces will be my marker and the ground of tweetopia is my map model.

Here's an illustration https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSuix.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I play around with the TrackballControls.js of draggable cubes and it seems like it has controls.target = obj.position

Here's my solution to fly into the face of plane object

```
function toObj(obj) {
    var rotateTween = new TWEEN.Tween( controls.target )
        .to( { x: obj.position.x, y: obj.position.y, z: obj.position.z }, 4000 )
        .interpolation(TWEEN.Interpolation.CatmullRom)
        .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Quintic.InOut )
        .start();

    var goTween = new TWEEN.Tween( camera.position )
        .to( { x: obj.position.x, y: obj.position.y, z: obj.position.z + 10 }, 4000 )
        .interpolation(TWEEN.Interpolation.CatmullRom)
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quintic.InOut)

    goTween.start();

}
```